# Google+ APIs and Google+ Sign-in Deprecation & Sunset on Android Platform

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-games, google-signin

Recently, I got an email from Google that says :

> On March 7, 2019, all Google+ APIs and Google+ Sign-in will be shut
>   down completely. This will be a progressive shutdown beginning in late
>   January, with calls to these APIs starting to intermittently fail as
>   early as January 28, 2019.

In the following part of email :

> XXX GP (api-project-123123123123) plus v1 plus.people.get

I am using `com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient` and it's connection callbacks for providing sign-in functionality.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();
```

For the leaderboards and achievements :

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), 0);
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
                        "leaderboardX"), 0);
```

My app doesn't depend on deprecated Scopes here :
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/api-deprecation

In the new examples of Google Play Services on the Github repository : 
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

there is the new Google SignIn implementations and Game feature usage as you can see in the following code snippets.

For login :

```
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build());

mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
        new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
              Log.d(TAG, "signInSilently(): success");
              onConnected(task.getResult());
            } else {
              Log.d(TAG, "signInSilently(): failure", task.getException());
              onDisconnected();
            }
          }
        });
```

For game features :

```
@Override
  public void onShowAchievementsRequested() {
    mAchievementsClient.getAchievementsIntent()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_UNUSED);
          }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            handleException(e, getString(R.string.achievements_exception));
          }
        });
  }

  @Override
  public void onShowLeaderboardsRequested() {
    mLeaderboardsClient.getAllLeaderboardsIntent()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_UNUSED);
          }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            handleException(e, getString(R.string.leaderboards_exception));
          }
        });
  }
```

I am a bit confused here, do I have to implement the new SignIn and Leaderboard/Achievement API's?

Do I need to make a change for not being affected by Google+ APIs and Google+ Sign-in sunset?

Comment: Have you checked and verified if you're calling Google+ API's? You can check it using **`https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/plus.googleapis.com/metrics?project=mygoogleprojectname`**, replacing the `mygoogleprojectname` with whatever project Google claims to have detected the API usage from.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @jess, I have checked it and there are "plus.people.get" calls as stated in the email received from Google. The problem is, I can not match these http calls with my implementation. I have checked http calls on the client by using Charles proxy and couldn't see any call to "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/...". It might be a redirection or any backend call on the Google's authentication service.

Comment: How can I find that which API (Android, php, web) cause this "plus.people.get" calls? I will be glad if anyone can make a sugestion.

Comment: Please check this same issue in [github](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/555).

Answer (score 0):

The code you've pasted doesn't rely on Google+ APIs and shouldn't be affected by the Google+ shutdown.

Have you used any PLUS scope in an earlier version of your game, that might still be on some users devices? If your current code is ok, perhaps only some very old versions will be affected.

In the cloud developer console, APIs section for your project, you should be able to look at the traffic levels for the Google+ or Games APIs to see if they look like they have the potential to affect a large number of your users. You can also open up the Google+ API details there to see which specific methods are being called.